# Insert Google Spreadsheet document using Google Document List API and updating it

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I am very much confused with this. I tried a lot and I couldn't find a proper answer anywhere on the internet. My requirement is as follows.

I have to create a spreadsheet document and write data to it.

For authentication purposes, I am using client authentication (passing username and password to the service). So far I figured out the following.

```
DocumentListEntry newDoc = new SpreadsheetEntry();
newDoc.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("Favourite Product Template"));
DocsService service = new DocsService("dh-renaissance-v1");
service.setUserCredentials(username, password);
DocumentListEntry entry;
entry = service.insert(new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/"),newDoc);
```

Now, I know that I have to use Google Spreadsheets API to update the content of the document. The question is, how can I relate this document while using google spreadsheets api, so that I can modify it. I searched a lot and I found out ways to list multiple documents in the feed but I couldn't find out how I can get a single one.

Please help me out.

Thanks and Regards,

Pavan Andhukuri.